# Twig translate phrase with tags inside

Tags: php, symfony, twig, twig-extension

Twig version - latest

Twig extensions version - latest

---

I want to avoid html-tags in .po files

Here is text with link inside phrase.

`<p>{{ 'Click this <a href="/test/">test link</a>, friend' | trans | raw }}</p>`

Using solution from this topic - https://stackoverflow.com/a/11546933/2145125

`<p>{{ 'Click this %a_open%test link%a_close%, friend' | trans({'%a_open%' : '<a href="/test/">', '%a_close%' : '</a>'}) | raw }}</p>`

Having PHP-warning
`Warning: gettext() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given`

Compiled template PHP-code is

`echo gettext("Click this %a_open%test link%a_close%, friend", array("%a_open%" => "<a href=\"/test/\">", "%a_close%" => "</a>"));`

Comment: Is the end of your question the solution you found? Your question is unclear.

Comment: My question is how to use named-placeholders and avoid gettext warning.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache? Maybe try switch to using double quotes and just escape the ones you want to remain? Usage of the placeholders looks ok otherwise

Comment: Cache disabled. Double quotes have no effect.
Can you try to test twig template with one string? Does it works for you?

<p>{{ 'Click this %a_open%test link%a_close%, friend' | trans({'%a_open%' : '<a href="/test/">', '%a_close%' : '</a>'}) | raw }}</p>

Answer (score 3):

Found 2 solutions.

**trans + replace = gettext() + strtr()** You can use named placeholders like %a_open% etc., order of placeholders doesn't matter

```
<p>{{ 'Click this %a_open% test link %a_close% friend' | trans | replace ({"%a_open%" : '<a href="/test/">', "%a_close%" : "</a>"}) | raw }}</p>
```

**trans + format = gettext() + spritf**

```
<p>{{ 'Click this %stest link%s, friend' | trans | format('<a href="/test/">', '</a>') | raw }}</p>
```